# Ошибка соединения с сервером

Tags: mongodb, база-данных

Внезапно перестал коннектиться локальный mongodb:

```
$ mongoMongoDB shell version: 2.2.1connecting to: testSat Nov  3 23:30:53 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:91exception: connect failed
```

При этом `sudo service mongodb status` показывает:

```
mongodb stop/waiting
```

`sudo service mongodb restart` не помогает

`sudo service mongodb stop` выдает:

> stop: Unknown instance:

Без соединения с БД, шелл запускается: mongo --nodbНо при этом невозможно создать БД.

Есть какие-нибудь соображения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришлось переустановить.